# how to run mysql with single quotes in command line

Tags: mysql, linux, command

I need to run this command to grant user permission. And I did command from mysql client but it could not work.

```
mysql -u'user' -p'password' -h'10.10.10.8' -e "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'B2DD25340A1A8A4856A5399F0B';"
```

Comment: What is the error?  Normally, I would suspect you have a special character inside the double-quoted string, such as `$`, but I don't see that, here.

Comment: you could provide a proper error message and the version of your mysql db for further diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

put a backslash to escape the single quotes within the double quotes:

```
mysql -u'user' -p'password' -h'10.10.10.8' -e "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'user\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'B2DD25340A1A8A4856A5399F0B\';"
```

Comment: That should be unnecessary.  Single quotes inside double quotes should be handled correctly by the shell.